# Cannot get rid of spaces & margins between images

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

I have been working on a project where i have to put together images of excel sheets. It should look like a unique table from all the images, where the last two should be side by side. I have tried to write something, but the space between images and the margins between the last two images are giving me headaches right now. Your help will be very appreciated.

```
  //***CSS file

  .crop img 
   {
    height: 791px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 850px;
    display: block;
   }
  .LeftTable 
   {
     float: left;
   }

  .RightTable 
  {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;  //when increasing over 400px, the image on right gets closer but goes underneath of the one on left side.
  }


  //**HTML file
   <div class="crop">
      <img src="QATables/image1.png">
      <img src="QATables/image2.png">
      <img src="QATables/image3.png">
      <img src="QATables/image4.png">
      <div class="LeftTable">
         <img src="QATables/image5.png">
      </div>
      <div class="RightTable">
         <img src="QATables/image6.png">
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't space them out in the markup (newlines). Albeit small, the whitespace in the document is likely the cause.

Comment: I Have tried this: <img src="QATables/image5.png"><img src="QATables/image6.png"> before, but I did not get the expected result. That's why I created the two classes, which seem to get me close to te expected result (for side by side) but I still have margins in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to MathSquared11235's answer. It always helps to reset margins and padding. Let me say that again... it ALWAYS helps to reset margins and padding. Different browsers have different default margins and paddings, if you don't reset them, it will be impossible to make your website look the same among all browsers. And this could also be the problem you're currently facing as the browser you're using, may "add" unwanted margins or padding. And don't just reset them on a particular element such as suggested "div". I would recommended placing this at the top of your css...

// * { margin:0; padding:0; }

The asterisk (*) simply means "everything". So everything will have a margin of 0 and a padding of 0 until you add it yourself. Yes, you will need to add the wanted margin and padding to every element... but that's a good thing rather than allowing the browsers to individually decide that for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hitting every DOM element with that is pretty heavy handed. I much prefer a more measured approach like [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're doing, but I've answered the question as best I could.  If I misunderstood, please clarify and I'll try again.

Assuming you just want to make sure that the last image lines up perfectly with the second to last image, you can just change the float from right to left, here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mcabrams/qB9fA/

// relevant code:

```
 .LeftTable 
   {
     float: left;
   }

  .RightTable 
  {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not that clear. What I meant is I would like to have image1 to image6 without spaces between them in such a way that image1 to image4 are in portrait mode without spaces, then image5 and image6 are in lanscape mode, without margins. I am trying to recreate exactly the same Excel sheet (with images only!) with the first part of the table in portrait, and the last part in landscape mode, but no spaces or margins at all. I hope it will help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a difficult time visualizing what you're hoping to achieve.  Can you clarify on how this deviates from what I put together in the fiddle?  Is there any way you could upload a quick diagram (mspaint or whatever) showing the layout you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `.crop{ width: 1700px; }` and `.right{ float: left; }` it goes under because there are no space to put it next to the img of left.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2usCh/

Comment: I still have a margin between the last two images. Not very different from what I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Internet Explorer, know that it is very glitchy. I mean *very* glitchy. I read on another SO post which I, unfortunately, cannot find right now, that the cause of your glitch may be newlines in the HTML which IE *very helpfully* thinks are typographic spaces that you want to put into the text.

Also, you might do

```
div {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

if your layout permits. It will remove any space around the images.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Newlines *are* whitespace and this isn't unique to IE... and modern IE browsers *aren't* "very" glitchy.

Comment: I'm not aware of any browser that has margin and padding set on`div` in the browser style sheet, not even IE.